# Is it possible to get the terms of the posts that are included from the WP_Term_Query function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question that I cannot quite find the answer to.
Maybe I have overlooked it, but I am trying to achieve the following.

Is it possible to use the `WP_Term_Query` function and give a list of postid's.
And get back the categories (terms) that are linked to one or more posts?

Comment: See contributor notes in here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/. Does that help?

Comment: As far I can you are that the object_ids?